# Call .toJSON() on each Model in a Backbone Collection .filter()

Tags: backbone.js

I have this code:

```
        var products = kf.Collections.products.filter(function(product) {
            return product.get("NominalCode") == chargeType
        });

        if (products.length) {
            for (x in products) {
                products[x] = products[x].toJSON();
            }
        }

        return products;
```

Am I right in thinking there might be a more Backbone way of doing the `for in` loop?

Comment: I don't think there is. You could create a volatile collection, but that would mean more code executed, and it would mess the `collection` attribute inside your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your filter by using [Collection.where](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where)

> **where** collection.where(attributes)
>   Return an array of all the models in a collection that match the passed attributes. Useful for
>   simple cases of filter.

and you can remove your for loop by using [_.invoke](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke)

> **invoke**  _.invoke(list, methodName, [*arguments])
>   Calls the method named by *methodName* on each value in the list. Any extra
>   arguments passed to invoke will be forwarded on to the method
>   invocation.

These modifications could look like

```
var products = kf.Collections.products.where({
    NominalCode: chargeType
});

return _.invoke(products, 'toJSON');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/3vVKx/1/

If you don't mind changing the order of operations, with [chained methods](http://underscorejs.org/#chaining)

```
return kf.Collections.products.chain().
    invoke('toJSON').
    where({NominalCode: chargeType}).
    value()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/3vVKx/2/

Or as suggested by @kalley in the comments, a simple

```
_.where(kf.Collections.products.toJSON(), { NominalCode: chargeType })
```

Comment: You could also just `_.where(kf.Collections.products.toJSON(), { NominalCode: chargeType })`